# Where is jQuery UI combined package downloaded when insatlled using nuget

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, nuget

I have downloaded the jQuery UI Combined package using nuget in my MVC project using the command

`Install-Package jQuery.UI.Combined`

Now I have to add the `stylesheet(css)` reference of that package in on of my view, but I don't know where the `stylesheet(css)` is downloaded.

How can I find the path of all the files downloaded so that I can add the reference of the `stylesheet(css)`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked in App_Themes/Default or in Content?

UPDATED

I have git installed, so I can view changes. And this folders were modified after installing this NuGet Package:

Solution_folder\Project_folder\Content\themes\base\
Solution_folder\Project_folder\Content\themes\base\images\
Solution_folder\Project_folder\Scripts\
Solution_folder\packages\jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.4\Content\Content\themes\base\
Solution_folder\packages\jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.4\Content\Content\themes\base\images\
Solution_folder\packages\jQuery.UI.Combined.1.10.4\Content\Scripts\

Comment: found under `Solution_folder\Project_folder\Content\themes\base\`

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
Install-Package jQuery.UI.Combined -verbose
```

to see more information what is installed.

If you've already installed a package, you can use:

```
Update-Package jQuery.UI.Combined -Verbose -Reinstall
```